# Null pointer in view when run test android mocking

Tags: android, mockito, kotlin

I create test:

```
class MenuPresenterTest {

    lateinit var presenter: MenuPresenter
    lateinit var view: MenuView

    @Before fun setUp() {
        view = mock(MenuView::class.java)
        presenter = MenuPresenter()
    }

    @Test fun test_validation() {
        presenter.openActivity()
        verify(view).openActivity()
    }


}
```

MenuView

```
interface MenuView : MvpView {
    fun init()
    fun openActivity()
}
```

MenuPresenter

```
@PerActivity
class MenuPresenter @Inject constructor() : MvpPresenter<MenuView>() {

    fun initView(){
        view.init()
    }

    fun openActivity(){
        view.openActivity()
    }
}
```

MvpPresenter

```
open class MvpPresenter<V : MvpBaseView> : MvpBasePresenter<V>() {
    // things specific for current project

    override fun bindView(view: V) {
        super.bindView(view)
    }

    override fun unbindView() {
        super.unbindView()
        clear()
    }
}
```

MvpBasePresenter:

```
abstract class MvpBasePresenter<V : MvpBaseView> {
    private var viewRef: WeakReference<V>? = null
    private val disposables = CompositeDisposable()

    fun clear() = disposables.clear()
    fun dispose(disposable: Disposable) = disposables.add(disposable)

    open fun bindView(view: V) {
        viewRef = WeakReference(view)
    }

    open fun unbindView() {
        viewRef = null
    }

    fun isViewBound() = viewRef != null

    val view: V
        get() {
            if (viewRef == null) {
                throw NullPointerException("getView() called when viewRef is null. Ensure bindView(View view) is called first.")
            } else {
                return viewRef!!.get() as V
            }
        }


}
```

when I run test I get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: getView() called when viewRef is null. Ensure bindView(View view) is called first.
at base.MvpBasePresenter.getView(MvpBasePresenter.kt:27)
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MenuPresenter()` - you don't call `bindView` anywhere in your code, so the presenter has no idea about your mocked view. This means it cannot be anything but `null`.

Comment: that's it!!! I forgot add: presenter.bindView(view) in test class before call methods. Thx a lot!